# XML change element from "object" to "string"

Tags: php, xml

please someone help me?

I export products from the database via PHP to XML.
I'm using this code for that(short code):

**PHP:**

```
$my_file = "xml/my_xml_file.xml";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
while($new_query = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  $xml_file .= '<ELEMENT1>'.$new_query['element_data_text'].'</ELEMENT1>'.PHP_EOL;
}
fwrite($fh, $xml_file);
fclose($fh);
```

The code runs and saves a file in which I can see all the elements in order.
The above mentioned element looks like this:

**XML:**

```
<ELEMENT1>Consulted disposing to moonlight ye extremity. Engage piqued in on coming. </ELEMENT1>
```

The problem occurs when I import XML into my customer's application. The application will return an error:

*Bad data type of parameter [ELEMENT1], expected string, received object.*

Comment: Have you reached out to the customer and asked _them_ why it would be wrong?  In the exact example above, it wouldn't matter, but perhaps you have some data which would require the string to be inside [CDATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#CDATA_sections_in_XML) tags.

Comment: @PatrickQ customer response: "you send us bad data in a element1 that I don't know from the feed. Look at it from your side."

Comment: @PatrickQ When adding CDATA, the result is the same

Comment: Honestly, if they're not willing to tell you what's wrong, I'd tell them to bugger off.  The message is coming from _their_ system.  I don't think there's really anything we can do to help, based on the information you've given.

Comment: @NigelRen I'm sorry I wrote it to be 'code'@new_query'code'

Answer (score 2):

Here are two problems visible in the source you posted.

1. Your XML has no document element. It is invalid.
2. You do not escape/encode the value from the database. It can break the XML or change the structure.

I suggest using XMLWriter. It is an API for just this kind of job:

```
$data = [
  ['element_data_text' => 'example text'],  
  ['element_data_text' => 'with special chars: < &'],
  ['element_data_text' => 'with a <strong>tag</strong>']  
];

$fileName = 'php://stdout';
$writer = new XMLWriter;
$writer->openURI($fileName);
$writer->setIndent(2);
$writer->startDocument();
$writer->startElement('DATA');

foreach ($data as $record) {
    $writer->writeElement('ELEMENT1', $record['element_data_text']);
}

$writer->endElement();
$writer->endDocument();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DATA>
 <ELEMENT1>example text</ELEMENT1>
 <ELEMENT1>with special chars: &lt; &amp;</ELEMENT1>
 <ELEMENT1>with a &lt;strong&gt;tag&lt;/strong&gt;</ELEMENT1>
</DATA>
```

The message could happen because the library the client uses returns an error object or it does generic mapping from XML to object structures (like SimpleXML).

If you generate the XML as text you should encode the dynamic values using `htmlspecialchars()`.

```
$xml_file .= '<ELEMENT1>'.htmlspecialchars($new_query['element_data_text']).'</ELEMENT1>'.PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Hello,
xml has a complicated structure and the code would be too big to add it here ... That's why I just added part of the code.

I understand the use of "" but due to the time constraint, I need to correct my code above.

Comment: The problem could also arise under conditions ... in the old code I have a lot of "if, elseif" therefore I think it would be time consuming to modify the code according to you.

Comment: Well, if you generate XML as text, you should at least use `htmlspecialchars()` on the database values.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars()` I tried my problem it did not fix

Comment: Have you tried validating the generated file with an XML validator?

Comment: I tried through [xmlvalidation](http://xmlvalidation.com) he found no errors ... Interestingly, about 200 elements are fine but another 200 will end up in error.